# How to include a <script> tag on a Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

how to include a  tag on a Vue component

it's not just normal script but it inside

```
 <form class="checkout-form" name="checkoutForm" method="POST" action="/checkout">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.omise.co/omise.js"
              data-key="YOUR_PUCLIC_KEY"
              data-frame-label="Merchant site name"
              data-frame-description="Merchant site description"
              data-default-payment-method="bill_payment_tesco_lotus"
              data-other-payment-methods="internet_banking, bill_payment_tesco_lotus, alipay, credit_card"
              data-amount="10025"
              data-currency="usd"
              data-button-label="Click to see an example">
      </script>
    </form>
```

Comment: Looking at https://www.omise.co/omise-js-api, there are alternative ways to use the Omise API without requiring the script inside the form.

Answer (score 2):

In my option, this code is better way, use **vuemeta**

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      scriptOmine: {
        src: 'https://cdn.omise.co/omise.js'
        'data-key': 'YOUR_PUCLIC_KEY',
        'data-frame-label': 'Merchant site name',
        ...
      }
    }
  },
  metaInfo: {
    title: 'My Example App',
    bodyScript: [
      { src: 'js/example.js' },
      { this.scriptOmine }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is more simpler and readable

More doc: https://github.com/declandewet/vue-meta#script-object